# Linux/Grub boot to command line

Tags: linux, boot

Running Ubuntu 10.10.  My desktop environment is screwed up and won't let me use the keyboard or mouse at the login screen.  How can force a command prompt during boot?

EDIT - ANSWER
Here's a method:

`Alt-SysRq-e` - Requests kernel kill all processes except init.

Comment: Don't put your answer into your question. It goes down where the other answers are. You can even accept it in two days.

Answer (score 1):

If you boot into a linux liveCD, go to /etc/inittab

Look for something like :

```
id:3:initdefault:

[...]

x:5:respawn:/usr/bin/xdm -nodaemon
```

And modify too:

```
id:5:initdefault:

[...]

x:5:once:/bin/su - -- PREFERRED_USER -l -c '/usr/bin/startx </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1'
```

[From the Start X at Boot - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Start_X_at_boot)

Comment: It there a way to force a command prompt at boot without a live CD?  e.g. F8 in Windows.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is not.

Answer (score 1):

in grub, add the kernel command operation `init=/bin/sh`

Comment: How do I get to grub?  It boots to a graphical login screen and I can't use the keyboard or mouse at this screen.

Comment: So first grub boots up, and either gives you the option of which OS to boot into (that is the screen you want, and you have this screen if you dual-boot; hit `e` to edit things there), or doesn't and just shows you an ubuntu splash screen (too late to do anything). There may be a way to override it by holding down something, but I'm not positive. Has the keyboard ever worked before? You may have a change to hit ctrl-alt-f1 (and ctrl-alt-f7 to get back to graphical land) if you spam it during bootup, but I doubt this will work.